# Can I change permission on Vagrant synced_folder (vmware_fusion provider)

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vmware-fusion

I have a vmware_fusion provider box and I'd like to sync a working directory in the Vagrantfile during the `vagrant up --provider vmware_fusion`. According to the docs I can use `mount_options`, but when I've seen a few posts and the `mount_options` usually looks like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www", 
  id: "workbox",
  owner: "www-data",
  group: "www-data",
  mount_options: ["dmode=777,fmode=666"]

end
```

But I'm getting an error that says:

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

vmhgfs-fuse -o uid=`id -u www-data`,gid=33,allow_other,dmode=777,fmode=666 '.host:/workbox' /var/www
```

Is there something unique to using `mount_options` with a vmware_fusion provider box? The box is Ubuntu 14.04 and one that I custom built.

The goal is to be able to add vhosts, do work locally and be able to browse to see changes.

Comment: What's the host OS? Did you look at the `--debug` output to see if there is any additional info?

Comment: My host machine is a Mac running 10.10.5. I'm seeing `fuse: unknown option dmode=777'`

Comment: I have a feeling the `dmode` and `fmode` are different for the vmware fusion plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think *vmhgfs-fuse* has a mode to set the directory permission but you can use `umask` property to set the permissions on your file

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www", 
    id: "workbox",
    owner: "www-data",
    group: "www-data",
    umask: "666"

end
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried out the umask, just learning about umask in general now. But even when I change permissions I'm unable to change the owner of any directories and files in the synced folder. `chown: changing ownership of ‘index.php’: Operation not permitted`. I think my goal for changing ownership is not necessary if what I'm trying to do is have php-fpm pool configuration files. The `www-data` that I set when I `vagrant up` works for the php-fpm pools I have.